# При нажатии на внутренний div так же нажимается и внешний div

Tags: html, css

Когда я нажимаю на min-block так же нажимается block, как мне сделать так чтобы при нажатии min-block block не нажимался. z-index не помагает.

```css
.block {
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #212121;
}

.block:active {
    background-color: #424242;
    transition: 0.15s;
}

.min-block {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #FF1744;
    transition: 0.15s;
}

.min-block:active {
    background-color: #00C853;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title></title>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

    <body>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="min-block">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing может в этой стороне Вы найдете ответ

Comment: В целом: так работают события в js, ссылку вам дали выше на объяснение. В каком именно коде js-скрипта возникает ошибка? Что именно вы там хотите сделать, где мешает такое нажатие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся информация по этой ссылке https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing
Если кратко: в onClick элемента нужно добавить `event.stopPropagation()`, тогда всплытие вашего onclick остановиться на данном элементе

```
    <body onclick="alert(`сюда всплытие не дойдёт`)">
       <button onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Кликни меня</button>
    </body>
```